# Center two SVGs in DIV

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to vertically and horizontally center two separate SVGs inside a DIV. I also want them to be responsive and scale with the DIV rectangle when the page is resized.

I'm trying to build this:

[Mockup of site I'm trying to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvXnt.png)

I'm currently trying to use Flexbox and I've got the images centered, but they're on separate lines currently.

```
.container {
    background-color: #0000ff;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    width:70%;
    height:4em;
    margin: auto;}

.containernest {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;
    height: 6em;}
```

There also seems to be some browser issue going on, as you can see from the image below:

[Example of my browser issue (Chrome vs Safari)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpCh0.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: adding `flex-direction: row` to the container will align your two child elements in a single row.

Comment: ^^ I'd also recommend checking out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for more info on flexbox.

Comment: I would put them in the same SVG. You make the first SVG wider, you change the second SVG in a `g` or a `symbol` and translate it as much as you need. If your SVG has only viewBox but no width and height, will be responsive.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)